# Installed extensions disappear after a while of itself

Tags: extensions, magento2.2.7

In **`Magento2 version 2.2.7`**, installed extensions will disappear after a while of itself.
These are different modules like:

- honl/magento2-nl-nl (Translation to Dutch)
- myparcelnl/magento (Shipping module of a transport company)
- mollie/magento2 (Molly Payments, speaks for itself)

I can reinstall and set it up, then everything will work again. but to a period this has to happen again.
Unfortunately, I have not yet found out what time period this is.

Answer (score 0):

It's either a deployment issue or somebody actually doing this.

Module-Status is defined in `app/etc/config.php` maybe you are overwriting that file in your deployment/continous integration?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. (I only see your message now :()
In the meantime I have re-installed magento (several times), and a solution seems to have been found for all problems.
I still do not understand why the extensions have disappeared automatically. Now, fortunately, I no longer suffer from it.